# How to convert PDF to PSD with layers

Tags: pdf, file-converter, photoshop, psd

I have designed a cover book with `TikZ` which the output is normally a `.pdf` file. Now the publisher wants me an open-layered `.tiff` and although I know how to convert it to files like `.jpg` or `.psd`, but my problem is that these files are just one layer. Is there any way to convert the original `.pdf` (which is made by `.TikZ`) to open-layered `.tiff` or `.psd`?

Comment: try to ask in [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I am reasonably sure that [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) can do this but you will have to do some digging to find the correct set of options. It can certainly generate TIFFs from PDFs, can definitely generate multi-layer TIFFs and I have seen some discussion on support for multi-layer PS files as well.

ImageMagick is a **very** powerful, command line based tool for manipulating, converting and creating images.

It is:

- Free, Gratis
- Free, Open Source
- Cross Platform *including Windows, Mac & Linux*
- There is lots of online help & the authors are very helpful people *but remember that they are doing all this for free*
- Some [Examples](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/) from the Official Site
- Also see [Fred's ImageMagick Scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the conversion to layered PSD using Photoshop but that is not a cheap option unless you already own Photoshop. I don't own photoshop but here is a link describing the process. [Link describing process.](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-convert-pdfs-to-layered-psds) There may be some web-based solutions. You should google your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have photoshop you can cut around each bit that needs to be a separate layer and paste it into a new layer, however this requires some time if you're not familiar with Photoshop and obviously requires Photoshop itself.